# Sort a list using lodash on knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, lodash

I tried to sort in the following ways. I am facing the exception `handlerfunction apply is not a function`.

```js
_ self.reviews= ko.observableArray([]);
```

Method 1:

```js
_.orderBy(self.reviews(), [{ 'Name' :String }], ['asc'])
```

Method2:

```js
_.orderBy(self.reviews(), [{ 'Name'}], ['asc'])
```

Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're wrapping the name of the order property in an object. It should just be a plain string, same as the order direction.

```js
_.orderBy(self.reviews(), ['Name'], ['asc']) ;
```